# Rails - a way to check the last line while using smarter_csv gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, file, rubygems

I am using smarter_csv gem to parse a **large** CSV file on **Heroku**.

```
SmarterCSV.process(file_name, { chunk_size: 10, headers_in_file: false, user_provided_headers: user_provided_headers }) do |chunk|
  chunk.each do |row|
    # parse row
  end
end
```

Is there any way to check if the row is the last line?

Comment: What do you want to do if the row is the last line? I ask purely because there *might* be a trivial solution involving simply adding an extra line of code *after* the `each` loop.

Comment: Hi @TomLord, I am just going to skip parsing for the last line.

Answer (score 0):

SmarterCSV does not seem to have any utility for this, so I think the only way is to count the number of lines before and while processing:

```rb
line_count = `wc -l < file_name`.to_i
lines_processed = 0
SmarterCSV.process(file_name, { chunk_size: 10, headers_in_file: false, user_provided_headers: user_provided_headers }) do |chunk|
  chunk.each do |row|
    lines_processed += 1
    return if lines_processed == line_count
    # parse row
  end
end
```

Comment: You should use `next` or `break` instead of `return` in the `each` loop

Answer (score 0):

`smarter_csv` does not do a read-ahead, so there is no way to know if the current row is the last row in the file.

The only way to do this would be to count the number of lines in advance, and then recognize the last line.